# Substring with range out of bounds?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

Okay, so this is a bit confusing (well to me). I have a string that has a single number I want out of it. I have surrounded this number with '/' so that I will be able to get that number out of it later.

Here is how I am getting the number out of it:

```
if ([MYSTRING hasSuffix:@"mp"]) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        char looking = '/';
        for(int i=0; i < MYSTRING.length; i++){
            if (looking == [MYSTRING characterAtIndex:i]) {
                if (start == 0) {
                    start = i;
                }
                else{
                    end = i + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", MYSTRING); //When i NSLOG here i get '2012-06-21 03:58:00 +0000/1/mp', 1 is the number i want out of the string, but this number could also change to 55 or whatever the user has
        NSLog(@"start: %i, end: %i", start, end); //When i NSLOG here i get 'start: 25, end: 28'
        NSString *number = [MYSTRING substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, end)];
        number = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
        if ([number intValue] > numberInt) {
            numberInt = [number intValue];
        }
```

It keeps crashing and the console says:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1875d72 0x106ce51 0x1875b4b 0x184ea64 0x3a6c 0x1080713 0x1bf59 0x1bef1 0xd532e 0xd588c 0xd49f5 0x49a2f 0x49c42 0x290fe 0x1b3fd 0x17d2f39 0x17d2c10 0x17ebda5 0x17ebb12 0x181cb46 0x181bed4 0x181bdab 0x17d1923 0x17d17a8 0x18e71 0x200d 0x1f35)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

From my counting the range is within the bounds, I dont get why I am getting this error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: somebody else is probably going to answer your question pretty quick, but one thing I wanted to point out a.s.a.p. was to *never* use all caps (or Capitalize) the name of a variable, like "`MYSTRING`".  All caps might be appropriate for Constants, but another preferred style is to prefix a Konstant with a K (or lower case k).

Comment: Oh i only did it so it is noticeable for you guys :), its not like that in code

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your NSMakeRange(start, end) should be NSMakeRange(start, end- start);

Answer (score 8):

I think you have confusion in syntax of NSMakeRange. It is something like this

```
NSMakeRange(<#NSUInteger loc#>, <#NSUInteger len#>)
```

`<#NSUInteger loc#>:` It is the location from where you want to start picking or substring.

`<#NSUInteger len#>:` This is the length of your output or substring.

Example:

Mytest12test

Now I want to pick'12'

so:

```
NSString *t=@"Mytest12test";
NSString *x=[t substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 2)] ;
```

**In your code instead of length you are passing index of end  character that is your mistake.**

Comment: NSMakeRange(<#NSUInteger loc#>, <#NSUInteger len#>) this made  a lot clear

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your are using this approach, but iOS provides a string function which separates a string with respect to another string and returns an array of the components. See the following example:

```
NSString * str = @"dadsada/2/dsadsa";
NSArray *listItems = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *component = [listItems objectAtIndex:1];
```

Now your component string should have 2 store in it.

Comment: I never knew there was such a function, Could you possibly provide a bit of code relative to my example to help me understand exactly how that function works? Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler runs into this code...

```
else{   
    end = i + 1;
}
```

... in the last iteration of the loop, it sets the end variable to one **more** then the range of `MYSTRING`. This is why you are getting that error. To fix it, just do this:

```
else{   
    end = i;
}
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. Saleh's approach is a simpler way of accomplishing what you want

------UPDATE------

You should do it like this actually:

```
NSMutableArray *occurencesOfSlashes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
char looking = '/';
for(int i=0; i < MYSTRING.length; i++){
if ([MYSTRING characterAtIndex:i] == looking) {
    [occurencesOfSlashes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];  
}
NSString *finalString = [MYSTRING substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([occurencesOfSlashes objectAtIndex:0],[occurencesOfSlashes objectAtIndex:1])];
```