# iOS 8 long is not work for NSMakeRange()

Tags: ios, ios8

can not use int in 64 bit app. now trying to use long. But it is not working in NSMakeRange

```
long i;
for (long i = 0;i<4;i++){     
    NSLog(@"range:--- %ld",i);

    range.location= i; //possibly crash here
    subStr =[str substringWithRange:range];
}
```

Error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {1, 1} out of bounds; string length 1'
```

Comment: could you post error message ?
is Range or index out of bounds ?
try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131472/substring-with-range-out-of-bounds

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {1, 1} out of bounds; string length 1'

Comment: Use NSInteger instead of long to support 64-bit correctly. Your crash is caused by trying to substring a string smaller than the range you specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're crash has nothing to do work your use of `long`. It is because your string is only 1 character long, so the range for the entire string is {0, 1}.

Answer (score 0):

It was mistake to convert the long value into my desired format.

suppose, I have a number 4. its one digit only.
but when i convert it into NSString i need 0004. but i for to convert str.

Now I solved it:
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04lu", k];

Then it works Fine. :)

Thanks All.